# I am unable to set basic authentication headers

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie in angular. I'm trying to send a GET request to server with basic authentication headers, but it didn't work. Here is my code,

```
///////////////My app.js///////////////
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=';
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'UserController',
        templateUrl: './app/views/homepage.html'
    })  
    .when('/users', {
        controller: 'UserController',
        templateUrl: './app/views/userlist.html'
    });
}]);

///////////////My userService.js///////////////
myApp.factory('UserService', function($http){
var factory = {};
var urlBase = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api';
    factory.getUsers = function(){
        return $http.get(urlBase+'/getusers');
    };
    return factory;
});
```

When I called the service from controller, There were 2 errors shown in the browser's console,

- OPTIONS http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/getusers
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/getusers. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

While I send request via POSTMAN app, it work normally.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a cross-domain-request issue

Postman is an extension

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and
> receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same
> origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to
> remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests
> cross-origin permissions.

For  development purpose you can simply disable chrome's `--disable-web-security`,this will do the job for you.

**or**

You can simply use this chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Comment: The browser's console showed 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/getusers'. Invalid HTTP status code 401

Is it about authentication header ?

Comment: that is because our access--token is either expired or is invalid

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS issue. Your server should set up some basic CORS filters. There are already a lot of questions asked and answered on this.

Answer (score 0):

CORS error solved by backend developer. so I think contact your backend developer....